Debian Bookworm - Install Canon MF443dw scanner
I have taken home from the office a Canon MF443dw multifunction printer, but I have some hard time to get the scanner working. I have tried to get it working with both sane.d and Gnome Document Scanner, but without any success.
I have tried to follow this guide SuperUser - How to use to a Canon Pixma scanner in GNU/Linux using sane, and over a local network, e.g. Wi-Fi?
It's connected to the same network as the computer is. I can see in Wireshark that sane.d is trying to find a scanner both on subnet broadcast, global broadcast, and on the scanners IP address i provided in pixma.conf but without any respons from the scanner. Just to clearify, the scanners IP is 192.168.1.174.
Is MF443dw not a pixma scanner? Do i use wrong protocol (bjnp://)? Do I need to enable something on the scanner? Or is there other tricks to get it working?

Install the driver from canon website. The installer script can find the scanner in your Network or connected through USB. Driver webpage
